# Create dictionary of dictionaries of lists in one line

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

Any way to create dictionary of dictionaries of lists in one line?

```
names = ['alex', 'ben', 'coby']
age = ['20', '30', '40', '50']

name_age = {n: {} for n in names}
for n in names:
    name_age[n] = {a: {} for a in age}
```

Nesting such as below does not work.

```
name_age = {n: {{a: {} for a in age}} for n in names}
```

Comment: `name_age = {n: {a: {} for a in age} for n in names}`

Comment: Correct answer, please post. Tried it myself but must have made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way of constructing a dictionary based on two lists is iterating them at the same time with `zip`. This will work:

```py
names = ['alex', 'ben', 'coby']
age = ['20', '30', '40', '50']

name_age = dict(zip(names, age))

print(name_age)

>>> {'alex': '40', 'ben': '50', 'coby': '20'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
names = ['alex', 'ben', 'coby']
ages = ['20', '30', '40', '50']

result =  { names[index]:ages[index] for index in range(len(names)) }

print(result)
```

{'alex': '20', 'ben': '30', 'coby': '40'}